expected value of the degree of a node's neighbor is larger than the expected value of the node's degree
Im trying to prove a certain property for the friendship paradox, which is basically showing that the expected degree of a node's friend is larger than the expected value of a node's degree.
mathematically:-
let V be a random variable for a random vertex in a graph, then V~Uni(|V|)
then $ p(v) = \frac{d(v)}{2|E|} $ which is basically the degree of the node divided by the entire relationships of the graph.
thus $ \mathbb{E}[d(x)] = \frac{\sum d(v)}{|V|} = \frac{2|E|}{|V|} $
now let y be a random variable for a node's friend (neighbor), how can I achieve that
$ \mathbb{E}[d(y)] \geq \mathbb{E}[d(x)] $
thanks for any help.

What is $p(v) = \frac{d(v)}{2|E|}$?

The probability of selecting $v$ as a node's friend from node $u$ is $\frac{1}{d(u)}$. The probability of selecting $u$ in the first place is $\frac{1}{|V|}$. The sum of product of these values, for all friends of $v$ signifies the total probability of it being selected:
$$\begin{split}
P(y = v) &= \sum_{(u, v) \in E}\frac{1}{|V|d(u)} \quad \text{ , and then} \\
\mathbb{E}[d(y)] &= \sum_{v \in V} P(y=v) \cdot d(v) \\
&= \sum_{v \in V} \left(d(v) \cdot \sum_{(u, v) \in E}\frac{1}{|V|d(u)}\right) \\
&= \sum_{v \in V} \sum_{(u, v) \in E}\frac{d(v)}{|V|d(u)} \\
&= \frac{1}{|V|} \sum_{v \in V} \sum_{(u, v) \in E}\frac{d(v)}{d(u)} \\
&= \frac{1}{|V|} \cdot \sum_{(u, v) \in E} \left( \frac{d(v)}{d(u)} + \frac{d(u)}{d(v)} \right) \\
&\ge \frac{1}{|V|} \cdot \sum_{(u, v) \in E}  2  \\
&= \frac{2|E|}{|V|} \quad \text{ , or} \\
\mathbb{E}[d(y)] &\geq \mathbb{E}[d(x)] \\
\end{split}$$
